# EmguCV - Process a video and capture frames as images

Tags: c#, video-processing, emgucv, image-capture

New to EmguCV, so need an opinion on this scenario.  I have a video which shows - 3 Pages ,

(i.e) first it shows Page1 then after 10 seconds it will update to Page2 and finally after a few seconds - Page3 .

I am looking to get these 3 frames as images . Whenever the Page in the video updates i need to take capture of that screen and save it as an image.

Answer (score 0):

Do the pages have readily identifiable markings? Or are they just 3 pages of text? If there are identifiable marking are they in the same place on each page? If so then find that location and do a comparison frame to frame and when the comparison show a difference save the new page, use the marking from the new page to identify the 3rd page using the same technique. Essentially find the distinguishing features and use them to determine when a page changes.

If they are plain text you might try an OCR of a small section or maybe KNN to detect the change.

Doug